# What does “withdrawn” status mean for a JSR that was final?

Tags: java, php, jsr

I've read [What does "withdrawn" status mean for a JSR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536500/what-does-withdrawn-status-mean-for-a-jsr) and as far as I've understood it's about the case when withdrawal was done before finalizing.

How about the case when it was final and is used widely,
like https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223?

> Status: Withdrawn Reason: Withdrawn in December 2016 following the
>   Maintenance Review. JCP version in use: 2.10 Java Specification
>   Participation Agreement version in use: 2.0
>
> Description: The specification will describe mechanisms allowing
>   scripting language programs to access information developed in the
>   Java Platform and allowing scripting language pages to be used in Java
>   Server-side Applications.

Comment: I have no solid knowledge but could it just be that something that was addressed over a decade ago is no longer considered valid and was either replaced or merged with another JSR? The timeline would suggest something like that.

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: @Nico Haase, 223 is for scripting languages support, from text: `The specification will be grounded on at least one concrete scripting language example, PHP`